# How can I invalidate a session of a user on a rails devise app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to create an endpoint that will invalidate user session.
I understand that devise has `destroy_user_session` route that will destroy the user session. But how can I do that for a specific user from an admin point of view? Where does devise store session data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where does devise store session data?

Devise will use the session store that your Rails app is configured to use. The key used is determined by what you pass to `devise_for` in your `config/routes.rb` file - which is known as the Devise mapping. See [Devise::Controller::Rememberable](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/451ff6d49c71e543962d2b29d77f2e744b2d47e1/lib/devise/controllers/rememberable.rb#L22).

The default session storage in Rails has been ActionDispatch::CookieStore since at least Rails 4 so the session is actually "stored" by passing an encrypted cookie back and forth between the client and server. This is far more performant then the alternatives.

Thus you can't actually "invalidate" or destroy other users sessions while using the cookie store beacuse its not something you actually control. You can simply invalidate all the users cookies by changing the application secret which will cause Rails to reject any existing session storage cookies and issue new ones.

If you want to be able to implement such a feature you need to change the session storage backend into server side storage such as [Redis](https://github.com/roidrage/redis-session-store) or [ActiveRecord](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store) which will actually let you find a session for a specific user and delete it. Before doing so you should read up as much as possible about [how sessions work in Rails](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-rails-sessions-work/) and the basics of how Devise together with [Warden](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBJ3G40fxHg) handles user authentication as you'll need a solid grasp of that to implement the feature. The performance implications should also be considered as it will impact your entire application.

Comment: I'm not going to go into the specifics of how to actually implement the feature as it depends on what backend you end up using and would be way to wide in scope.

Comment: There is also an alternative path which I haven't actually tried but which should theoretically work which is that you add a column to the users table which acts as a flag like for example `add_column :users, :force_logout_at, :datetime` and you would then use Warden::Hooks to reject the user if the column is set. This would work without swapping the session storage.